# Find table fields and their properties in Axapta AOT

Tags: axapta

I would like to query the Axapta AOT to find the fields of a given table and their properties. Could you please provide some code examples? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static void Job68(Args _args)
{

    TreeNode node = TreeNode::findNode(@'\Data dictionary\Tables\CustTable\Fields');
    TreeNode childNode;
    TreeNodeIterator nodeIT;


    nodeIt = node.AOTiterator();

    childNode = nodeIt.next();

    while(childNode)
    {
        info(strfmt("field %1", childNode.treeNodeName()));
        childNode = nodeIt.next();
    }
}
```